# didUpdateValueForCharacteristic not getting called on a reconnect

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

Using CoreBluetooth, I can connect to a new device, get services and characteristics, and receive updates for characteristics.

When I reconnect to a bonded device that has its client characteristic configuration descriptor written, I expected my peripheral delegate's didUpdateValueForCharacteristic to be called as soon as I connect to the device and set up my peripheral delegate.  This should happen according to the Bluetooth standard, but is not happening. Am I missing something or is this an iOS bug?

Note that it does get called if I do a setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic.

Comment: "This should happen according to the Bluetooth standard." Can you reference the part of spec that you mentioned?

Comment: Does the peripheral actually update a value on its characteristic when you reconnect? How are you sure?

Comment: @fatshu: The Bluetooth core spec (revision 4.0), page 1901 part G 3.3.3.3 says: "The Client Characteristic Configuration descriptor value shall be persistant across connections for bonded devices.... Each client has its own instantiation of the Client Characteristic Configuration."  So it is not explicit.  But most of the health service specs are: Heart rate service spec (version v10r00), page 10 3.1.1: When the Client Characteristic Configuration descriptor is configured for notification and a heart rate measurement is available, this characteristic shall be notified while in a connection.

Comment: @Wilhelmsen: I have access to the innards of a heart rate service and I am constantly updating the value of the heart rate measurement (for testing purposes).  But I don't receive it in the app until I do a setNotifyValue.

Comment: Where I need to call setNotify in my code?

Comment: Here's what I do: in my CBPeripheralDelegate's didDiscoverServices, for each service I call CBPeripheral's discoverCharacteristics:forService.  When the characteristics for a service are discovered, the callback CBPeripheralDelegate's didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService: gets called.  In this method I loop thru all characteristics of the service and call CBPeripheral's setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic with the appropriate characteristic.

Comment: I did the same. But didUpdateValueForCharacteristic only be called the odd times. For example, the first time, the third time, etc. What could be wrong?

Comment: Hello Mezulu, did you manage to solve this issue? It is now 7 years later and we are still experiencing this problem. You would think it would be fixed by Apple by now.